# How to Install my xcode project in other developer device for testing

Tags: ios, xcode

I used to test my xcode project in my phone using a cable

But now I want to install the app to my friend device for testing and when I do some change or update to the code, my friend gets the update remotely either automatically or via a link

Is that possible in xcode? If so, how?

Comment: You need more than Xcode. You can register your friend's device or (I think)use TestFlight but either way, you'll need to be a registered developer (and probably entail the US$99 annual fee) at http://developer.apple.com.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your friend as an internal beta tester on [TestFlight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/) and push releases to them whenever you have something new to show. You can automate this via [Fastlane](https://fastlane.tools/) and hook that up to TestFlight and have it happen automatically, whenever you commit code to a certain branch. That's probably overkill though. I'd just use TestFlight directly.

As @dfd helpfully pointed out in the comments, using TestFlight requires being part of the [Apple Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/), which costs $99/year. It's also necessary to be a part of that program if you want to release to the App Store.

Comment: As noted in my comment, it also means being a registered (and US$99 fee) at http://developer.apple.com - but I agree, TestFlight is the most seamless way. I *think* you could just have an AppleID, be registered without the fee, and register the device... but with bypassing the fee you cannot use TestFlight.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation guys